# while loop for largest and smallest values Error

Tags: c

if the user exits (enter -1) immediately, the smallest number show 100000 instead of 0, which also happens when writing a sequence list (1,2,3,4, etc) please help. i tried using do-while loop but same issue as well.

here is the task:

Write a program that continues to get numbers from the user until the user enters -1. Finally, your program will show the biggest and smallest numbers.

```
Output (with sequence list)     
                                       
 To Exit Enter (-1)
 enter a number: 1
 enter a number: 2
 enter a number: 3
 enter a number: 4
 enter a number: 5
 enter a number: -1

Largest Number: 5
 Smallest number: 10000000

output (with random numbers)
 To Exit Enter (-1)
 enter a number: 33
 enter a number: 12
 enter a number: 50
 enter a number: 6
 enter a number: 10
 enter a number: -1

 Largest Number: 50
 Smallest number: 6

output (when existing immediately)
 To Exit Enter (-1)
 enter a number: -1

 Largest Number: 0
 Smallest number: 10000000
```

my code:

```
 int main()
    {
        int num, minimum=10000000 , max=0;
        int choice;
        printf(" To Exit Enter (-1)\n");
        
        while(num!=-1)
        {
        
            printf(" enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            
            if(num>max)
            {
                max=num;
            }
            
            else if(num<minimum && num!=-1)
            {
                minimum=num;
            }
        }
    
    
            printf("\n Largest Number: %d \n Smallest number: %d",max,minimum);
    }
```

Comment: You also only check if `num < minimum` if `num` _isn't_ greater than `max`. In your example input, `num > max` is always true (until you enter `-1` which is its own special case), so the `else if` branch is never entered.

Comment: Suggest you learn to do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and trace its flow and variable values as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: while(1){scanf(num);if(num==-1)break; min-max thing;} write min and max. use INT_MAX and INT_MIN.

Comment: @NathanPierson sorry i didn't quite understand what you meant in testing the value of num before initializing it

Comment: `while(num != 1)` checks whether `num` is equal to `1` at the beginning of the loop. The first time through the loop, `num` has been declared but not initialized, so it's undefined behavior to read its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the else will solve the problem:

```
int main()
    {
        int num, minimum=10000000 , max=0;
        int choice;
        printf(" To Exit Enter (-1)\n");
        
        while(num!=-1)
        {
        
            printf(" enter a number: ");
            scanf("%d",&num);
            
            if(num>max)
            {
                max=num;
            }
            
            if(num<minimum && num!=-1)
            {
                minimum=num;
            }
        }
    
    
            printf("\n Largest Number: %d \n Smallest number: %d",max,minimum);
    }
```

the problem was that the if condition was always true because you were entering ascending numbers so the else condition was never executed